# Operator Norm: Why is this formulation so rarely seen?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

There are many equivalent definitions for the norm $||T||$ of a linear operator $T:X\to Y$. Citing the Wikipedia and some books about functional analysis, the equivalence of definitions are often stated as
$$\begin{align}
||T|| &= \inf\{M\ge0 ; ||Tx||\le M||x||\} \\
&= \sup\{\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}; x\in X/\{0\} \} \\
&= \sup\{||Tx||;x\in B[0,1] \} \\
&= \sup\{||Tx||;x\in S \} \\
\end{align}$$
where $B[0,1]=\{x\in X;||x||\le 1\}$ and $S=\{x\in X; ||x||=1\}$. I am curious as to why we don't normally see the formulation
$$
||T||=\sup\{||Tx||;x\in B(0,1) \} \\
$$
where $B(0,1)=\{x\in X;||x||< 1\}$?

I try to make this not opinion based as much as possible but is there a valid reason why this expression is not usually seen? I asked a professor who worked mainly on the theory of Banach space and he said he didn't know. (He even suspected, on first sight, that it might not be true since he has never seen it)

Comment: Is it not rather $\sup\biggl\{\dfrac{\lVert Tx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}\;;\;x\in B(0,1)\biggr\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the main argument would be that this formulation is not really advantageous. The thing is that for $\dim X < \infty$, $B[0,1]$ and $S$ are compact and $\left\Vert Tx \right\Vert$ is continuous. Hence, there exists some $x_0 \in S$ such that 
$$\left\Vert T \right\Vert = \left\Vert Tx_0 \right\Vert$$
making the supremum a maximum. The supremum over $B(0,1)$ however will in general not be a maximum. Actually, if $T \not\equiv 0$, the supremum will only be achieved in $S$.

Comment: I've thought about this too and I think you might be correct that it's the reason why most people don't put it down in their book. However, I found some advantages in the sense that some proves can be shorten by adopting the formulation.

Comment: @BigbearZzz There may also be the (not very nice) possibility that authors just find it trivial that the $\sup$ of a continuous function over $B[0,1]$ is the same as the $\sup$ over its interior, i.e. $B(0,1)$. However, I can imagine that there are certain proofs which would benefit from this formulation.